# Can I add software logos in my video?

Tags: copyright, internet, software, youtube

I make a video about the AR filter that I created, showing my work process. Can I add logos of the applications that I used in this video?

And is there any official source fo these logos, or can I take it from the google search results?

I need to add icon for the following applications and brands:

- [SparkAR](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/)
- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)
- [Tilt Brush](https://www.tiltbrush.com/)
- [Oculus or Oculus Quest 2](https://www.oculus.com/quest-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your work is advertising your filter, and if the use of the names or logos might reasonably cause potential consumers to think your product was authorized or endorsed by the makers of any of those other products, thus would clearly constitute trademark infringement under US law.

Even if there is no suggestion of endorsement, if the video is advertising your filter, use of the logos (as opposed tom the names) of the other products would constitute trademark infringement.

The key provision of the law is [15 U.S.C. 1125 (Section 43 of the Lanham Act): False designations of origin, false descriptions, and dilution forbidden](https://www.bitlaw.com/source/15usc/1125.html).

Paragraph (a)(1)(A) forbids classic trademark infringement, where an actual trademark, or something confusingly similar to one, is used to deceive or confuse customers about “affiliation, connection, or association“ or “the origin, sponsorship, or approval of his or her goods, services, or commercial activities”. Paragraph (a)(1)(B) forbids use which misrepresents the source.

The actual law text is:

> (a)(1) Any person who, on or in connection with any goods or services, or any container for goods, uses in commerce any word, term, name, symbol, or device, or any combination thereof, or any false designation of origin, false or misleading description of fact, or false or misleading representation of fact,

> (A) is likely to cause confusion, or to cause mistake, or to deceive as to the affiliation, connection, or association of such person with another person, or as to the origin, sponsorship, or approval of his or her goods, services, or commercial activities by another person, or

> (B) in commercial advertising or promotion, misrepresents the nature, characteristics, qualities, or geographic origin of his or her or another person's goods, services, or commercial activities,

> shall be liable in a civil action by any person who believes that he or she is or is likely to be damaged by such act.

The trademark holder could sue and possibly collect significant damages.

See also the Law.SE Q&A [What are the license/legal requirements to write a guidebook about a specific product?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59807/what-are-the-license-legal-requirements-to-write-a-guidebook-about-a-specific-pr)